# Hibernate update one-to-one creates new child object instead of updating the existing one

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, orm

In my spring mvc app I have doctor and user tables in database. Every doctor has a user. The problem is when I try to update doctor, the user that belongs to doctor is not being updated. Instead of this I see a new user in my database that belongs to the updated doctor.

Here is my Doctor.java entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="doctor")
public class Doctor {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;


    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;


    @Column(name="tel")
    private String tel;

    @Column(name="email")
    @Email
    private String email;

    private transient String ConfirmPassword;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,  cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    //getter and setters....
```

And here is my User.java entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;


    @Column(name="username")
    private String username;


    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;


    //getters and setters...
}
```

Here is my form:

```
<form:form action="save" modelAttribute="doctor" method="post">

        <form:errors path="name"></form:errors>
        <form:input path="name" placeholder="Doktor İsmi" class="form-control" />

        <form:input path="user.username" placeholder="Kullanıcı Adı" class="form-control" />

        <form:input type="email" path="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" />

        <form:input path="tel" placeholder="Telefon" class="form-control" />

        <form:input type="password" path="user.password" placeholder="Şifre" class="form-control" />

        <form:hidden path="id" />/>
        <input type="submit" value="Doktor Kaydet" />
    </form:form>
```

Here is controller save method :

```
@PostMapping(value="/save")
    public String save(@Valid Doctor dr, @Valid User usr, BindingResult bindingResult){

        doctorValidator.validate(dr, bindingResult);
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "admin/doctor-form";
        }
        else{
            dr.getUser().setIs_doctor(1);
            doctorService.save(dr);
            return "redirect:list";
        }
    }
```

Finally here is DoctorDAO. Save method, I dont have extra save operation for user, because it should be saved via doctor.

```
public void save(Doctor dr) {
        Session s = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        s.saveOrUpdate("doctor", dr);

    }
```

I tried to read references, I have read examples and so on. I am beginner to Hibernate and JEE platform. I could not find a solution in two days.

Thanks,,

Comment: can you show us the save method itself?

Comment: I have included those methods now

Comment: during update, does the doctor and user have id set?

Comment: no, i directy update as above

Comment: how can you perform an update without the entities having their ids set?

Comment: the info is coming to update form from database, at the form I have the id of doctor. The doctor id comes from form. But as you say if I set user id at form it updates correctly. I just did not think that setting user id at form is a good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
public void save(Doctor dr) {
    Session s = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Doctor managedDr = s.merge(dr);
    managedDr.getUser().setIs_doctor(1);
    s.saveOrUpdate("doctor", managedDr);

}
```

Now, during merge, the User entity will fetched and when you perform the saveOrUpdate, it should update the user instead of inserting as the id will be there.

Comment: thank you so much, how come I have never saw this before

Comment: No worries. Glad i could help